# Calculating minimum cosine similarity score

Tags: python, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity

I am trying to retrieve the pair of documents with maximum and minimum cosine similarity scores in a corpus. 
This is my code for maximum similarity score:

```
def get_high_sim(self):
    """ Returns the maximum similarity score """
    flag = -1
    maximum = (flag, 0, 0)
    for d1 in self.sim_matrix.keys():
        for d2 in self.sim_matrix[d1].keys():
            if d1 != d2: #ignoring similarity with itself
                if self.active_clusters[d1] != -1 and self.active_clusters[d2] != -1: #checking if cluster is active
                    score = self.sim_matrix[d1][d2]
                    if score > flag and score != 1:
                        flag = score
                        maximum = (flag, d1, d2)
    return maximum
```

This seems to be working perfectly fine. But my code for minimum similarity score is not working.

```
    def get_lowest_sim(self):
    """ Returns the minimum similarity score in the corpus"""
    flag = -1
    minimum = (flag, 0, 0)
    for d1 in self.sim_matrix.keys():
        for d2 in self.sim_matrix[d1].keys():
            if d1 != d2: #ignoring similarity with itself
                if self.active_clusters[d1] != -1 and self.active_clusters[d2] != -1: #checking if cluster is active
                    score = self.sim_matrix[d1][d2]
                    if score < flag:
                        flag = score
                        minimum = (flag, d1, d2)
    return minimum
```

Can anybody help me spot the error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your actual output vs. the expected output?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the pair of documents from a corpus with max and min cosine similarity scores using group average link method for clustering. For documents with max similarity score this is my output: (0.30916661421588715, 'files/219.html', 'files/229.html')
where (score, doc1, doc2). I am trying to get a similar output for the min score as well. It works fine for the max score but shows an error for the min score.